# SQL: query repeating rows in join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display all my exercises which are in course A (course_id '1')

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM exercises 
LEFT JOIN sessions on sessions.session_id 
WHERE course_id ='1'
```

I get this:

[image: Query]

It's worth noting that courses have sessions and in that session there are these exercises. Realistically only exercise_id's 1 and 4 are linked to course 1. So why are their duplicate rows being returned? Session_id's 10, 11, 12 and 13 are all part of course 1 but do not have any exercises in them at present. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in condition of the join is missing the condition.

Try something like

`SELECT * FROM exercises LEFT JOIN sessions on exercises.session_id = sessions.session_id WHERE course_id ='1'`.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line:

```
LEFT JOIN sessions on sessions.session_id
```

You're not joining against a column in the other table. Without knowing your schema, I might guess it's exercises.session_id you might need to join on?